# Making apache to accept all subdomain requests that are not registered

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to configure apache to accept all subdomain request that including unregistered subdomains. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: You should note that dns must be configured to route all subdomen request to your server first, which most don't by default.

Comment: @Cthulhu how to configure DNS?

Comment: Depends on you DNS provider (usually the one you obtain domain name from). You probably have some control panel there...

Comment: @Cthulhu I'm using it on Windows 8 can I configure it using hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to simply not setup vhosts.  Alternatively, you can set up a default vhost.  From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#default):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
  DocumentRoot /www/default
</VirtualHost>
```